# Кодировка в dart

Tags: utf-8, dart, unicode, utf

Я делаю запрос на сервер и получаю html с русскими символами, вытаскиваю из него информацию и выдаю. Проблема в том, что символы отображаются вот так:
`[{\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0439: }]`

Я пробовал `utf8.decode(htmlResponse.bodyBytes)`, `String.fromCharCodes(string.runes)`
ничего не помогало. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы читаете текст [Прочитай](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) уже в Unicode (а не в кодировке utf-8). Скорее всего ничего перекодировать не надо, но если это обязательнов  в dart, то попробуйте перекодировать из utf-16

Answer (score 0):

Если сервер на php передавай так

```
json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```